# The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity too Large WCF

Tags: wcf-binding

I have a windows application to send image to server using WCF service. When I run my code and upload an image, WCF returns "The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large."

I have tried several ways from links but not solved.

The following is my WCF Config.

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
```

The following is app.config from Windows app.

```
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>

        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ILicencePhoto" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

       <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserLogging" >
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>

          <endpoint address="https://xxxxx/wcf/image.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILicencePhoto"
        contract="LicencePhoto.ILicencePhoto" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILicencePhoto" />       

 <endpoint address="https://xxxxx/wcf/user.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUserLogging" contract="UserLogging.IUserLogging"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserLogging" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I can log in with calling userWCF. The problem is when uploading user photo to WCF services. The user photo file size is only about 500KB max.

Thanks.
Nyi Nyi Aung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that we don’t apply the configuration on the server-side. Since the server-side uses ProtocolMapping feature to enable the service works over HTTPS protocol, we should modify and apply the configuration on the BasicHttpsBinding instead of the BasicHttpBinding.
Please refer to the below configuration(Server-side).

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding name="httpsBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Abraham, I have updated WCF config according to your advise but still not working...

Comment: Are you changing the right server side configuration since the client side has two different service endpoint addresses？ besides, are you using the service endpoint address over Https?

Comment: Yes... it is HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks Abraham, It fixed it now. After updating your advise I forgot to change my endpoint address(https) which was overwrite in code behind. It is working now.